# Getting error while making a new dag in apache airflow

Tags: airflow

PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG. Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

First , This is just a warning that for now but from version 2.0 of Airflow, it will raise exception, so can crash your pipeline if not handled (given you update airflow module)

Warning suggests that you are adding a task twice or using same id (`create_tag_template_field_result`) for two different tasks, which is causing this warning.

Comment: So how can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: by not adding same task twice